# StackOverflowException when using XamlWriter.Save() when trying to Clone a User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, clone, treeviewitem

I am using the below method to attempt to clone a TreeViewItem, but once it hits the `XamlWriter.Save()` it gives me a StackOverflowException.

The code that triggered this is :

```
 var b = Clone<TreeViewItem>(ViewTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem);
```

Where ViewTree is the name of my TreeView.

```
 public static T Clone<T>(T from) {
    string objStr = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(from);
    System.IO.StringReader stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(objStr);
    System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    object clone = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

    return (T)clone;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this TreeView has some cycle in it. For example: Some treeview node (or children of it children) has a child that point to the parent node. The StackOverflowException is generally for recursions out of memory.

Comment: In my case, each child item in the data-bound view model has a reference to its parent collection view model. Is that a problem? How can I teach XamlWriter.Save to handle this?

Comment: Maybe you can create an special node, some like `ParentReferenceTreeViewItem` without childrens, only with a property that points to the parent you want. The problem is when in the children there are an instance of a any parent node, then a loop is created.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
 System.Xaml.XamlServices.Save(obj);
```

from System.Xaml.dll

It handles circular references properly.